# is MaltParser the "Nivre" parser mentioned in Parsing to Stanford Dependencies Trade-offs between speed and accuracy?

Tags: parsing, nlp

hard to find rich info about Nivre parser, google lead to Maltparser, is it the same?

is it the one mentioned in the paper Parsing to Stanford Dependencies Trade-offs between speed and accuracy?

it performs quite well in the paper, why is it so unpopular?

Comment: Stanford Parser I believe is based on Collins parser, but ultimately dependency and syntactic parsing are different representations of the same parse, just a different presentation of results. Go read Collins' thesis or Nieve's book 'Inductive Dependency Parsing'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MaltParser is the implementation of all the algorithms published by Nivre et al. So whenever experimental data is reported for the Nivre algorithm(s), it is probably the result of running the MaltParser.

Answer (score 0):

well, I think it is. which can be realized from [here](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/stanford-dependencies.shtml)